# Question involving injective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be an algebra such that every ideal is a direct summand of $A$. Show that every $A$ module is injective.

$\textbf {My attempt:}$

Let $I$ be an ideal of $A$, considere another ideal $J$, since $J$ is direct summand of $A$ there exists $N$ such that $A = J \oplus N$.

Now, if we have a morphism $v: J \to I$ then the inclusion $j: J \to A = J\oplus N$ defines a morphism $w:A \to I$ s.t $w$ restricted to $J$ is equal to $v$. By Baer's criterion, we have $I$ injective.

So far we've shown that every ideal of $A$ is injective. Now, let $M$ be a finitely generated module, that is, $M = \langle m_1,m_2, \dots, m_n \rangle$, then $\psi: A^n \to M$ given by $\psi(a_1,\dots,a_n) = m_1a_1+ \cdots+m_na_n$ is epimorphism. Since $I$ is injective the follow short exact sequence splits

$$0 \to I \to A^n \overset{\psi}{\longrightarrow} M \to 0.  $$

Therefore, $A^n \simeq I \oplus M \simeq I \times M$ and $A$ is injective, so $M$ is injective.

My question is, how can I  prove that if $M$ is not finitely generated???

Comment: Your $\psi$ needs to go from $A^n$, sending $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ to $m_1a_1+\cdots+m_na_n$.

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't change the solution. I fixed that...

Comment: Apply Baer’s Criterion to an arbitrary module $M$, just like you did at the beginning to show that $I$ is injective.

Comment: Can you explain with more details?

Comment: It's been a while since I touched homological, but I guess you can do: Let $g: I \mapsto Q$, where $Q$ is some $A$-module. Now, you just need to provide a map $R\cong I \oplus N \mapsto Q$ such that the composition $I \mapsto I \oplus N \mapsto Q$ equals $g$. You can take $I \oplus N \mapsto Q$ to be the map $(i,n)\mapsto g(n)$, and now you should be done (By Baer's criterion you just need to check extension problems for all (left) ideals of A).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you were assuming commutativity, since you made no reference to sides. But really one can do this in noncommutative rings, and everything is symmetrical.

By Baer's criterion, if $M$ is a right $A$ module, you only need to check that every homomorphism $f:T\to M$ extends, where $T$ is a right ideal of $A$.

But it's always easy to extend to the complement of a summand, and $T$ is a summand by hypothesis.  This seems to be the part you are having a hard time seeing. If $T\oplus C=A$, you can use any homomorphism $g:C\to M$ at all (say the zero homomorphism) and then check $f\oplus g:T\oplus C\to M$.

What $f\oplus g$ means, in this case, is the map $t+c\mapsto f(t)+g(c)$. Since the sum is direct, this is well-defined, and really does produce an $A$ module homomorphism $A\to M$. Clearly it extends $f$ to all of $A$.

So, Baer's criterion is satisfied, and $M$ is injective.